# Fit a poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

can someone help me with this question[Fit a poisson dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34KMO.png)

I can't figure out from where to start .Appreciate if anyone knows how can i do it using R?

Comment: Could you please put your question in the question?

Comment: i have inserted the image as a link it has the question @LordSharktheUnknown